# SQL query optimisation advice

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a weird situation where a couple of sql queries + some simple php maths are taking upwards of 30 seconds + to execute.  I know the issue lies with the sql queries but I can't for the life of me think of a way to rewrite/optimise the queries.

Typically I'd swap to joins but because its a double sub select with maths I can't think of a way of doing it better.  Am I going down the right route doing it all in query or should I do 4 simple count selects and do all the maths in php.

Index's are built on all columns used in the where clauses.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblcontainergroups WHERE 
  (
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblmovements WHERE TicketStatus=1 AND MovementType=0 AND GroupID=tblcontainergroups.ID)
        -
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblmovements WHERE TicketStatus=1 AND MovementType=2 AND GroupID=tblcontainergroups.ID)
    )>0
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblcontainergroups WHERE 
  (
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblmovements WHERE TicketStatus=1 AND MovementType=0 AND GroupID=tblcontainergroups.ID)
        -
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblmovements WHERE TicketStatus=1 AND MovementType=2 AND GroupID=tblcontainergroups.ID)
    )>0 AND LENGTH(DateOfIncreases)>4
```

Then the php is a simple percentage of those 2 figures

```
$percentage = number_format(($total_with_increases/$total_active_groups)*100,2);
```

I know this is probably a really simple question and I'm probably being an idiot but is there a better way of doing this? can the queries be rewritten to not be so god damn slow.

**Table Structures**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tblcontainergroups`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblcontainergroups` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ContainerType` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `WasteType` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsHazardous` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PONumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SiteID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `SICProducer` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HasRentals` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DistanceText` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DistanceMeters` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IncreaseTrans` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IncreaseTonnage` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IncreaseWLHour` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IncreasesCompleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DateOfIncreases` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `VariousWasteTypes` text,
  `PremRequired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PremDescription` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=109454 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblmovements`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblmovements` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ClientID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SiteID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GroupID` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PONumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MovementType` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `WLHours` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Supplier` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OrderedBy` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SupplierNotes` text,
  `DateRequired` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppTransCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `TransMarkup` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `TransClientCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `SuppWeightRate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `WeightMarkup` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ClientWeightCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `SupplierIncMinTonnes` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ClientIncMinTonnes` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `TonnesClientCharge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `TonneageType` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppWLRate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `WLMarkup` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `WLClientRate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `CreatedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TicketStatus` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `IsInvoiced` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `GGOrderNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OrderSubmitted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ParentTicket` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppWLHours` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ClientWLHours` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `WasteDestination` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TicketWeight` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `VHCReg` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SupplierContact` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ComplianceNotes` text,
  `WeightAddedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RateSetBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsCompleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DateWeightAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RebateRate` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `InvoiceNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsPaid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `InvoiceDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ActualRebate` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `RebateToClient` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `SupplierWeightContact` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VHCAddedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OldTicketNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BelongsToWR` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OkInvoice` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DeletionDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SupplierInvNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppTicketNo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppIsDisputed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppDateDisputed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppDisputedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppDateDisputeCleared` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppDisputeClearedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppIsPaid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppPaidOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuppPaidBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TicketApproveReason` text,
  `ComplianceCopyTicket` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppInvCheckedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SuppCheckDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SupplierOrderConfirmedBy` text,
  `OrderConfirmationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderConfirmedUser` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TicketReceived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DisputeReason` text,
  `DisputeType` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DisputeClearReason` text,
  `ClientIsDisputed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClientDateDisputed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClientDisputedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClientDisputeReason` text,
  `ClientDisputeType` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClientDateDisputeCleared` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClientDisputeClearedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ClientDisputeClearReason` text,
  `CarbonUsageKGKM` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `CarbonUsageKGL` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SuppTonneageType` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TicketApprovedBy` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TicketApprovedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsLate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RoRoProcessed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LeadOwnerBDM` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastComplianceUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsDummy` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `DisputerName` text,
  `DisputerContact` text,
  `ClientDisputerName` text,
  `ClientDisputerContact` text,
  `MarginsProcessed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OrigCreator` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AccountsSent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NoRebate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `WTNCreated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=368401 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tblcontainergroups`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblcontainergroups`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `ContainerType` (`ContainerType`), ADD KEY `WasteType` (`WasteType`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tblmovements`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblmovements`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `ClientID` (`ClientID`), ADD KEY `SiteID` (`SiteID`), ADD KEY `GroupID` (`GroupID`), ADD KEY `Supplier` (`Supplier`), ADD KEY `OrderedBy` (`OrderedBy`), ADD KEY `CreatedBy` (`CreatedBy`), ADD KEY `GGOrderNumber` (`GGOrderNumber`), ADD KEY `WasteDestination` (`WasteDestination`), ADD KEY `WeightAddedBy` (`WeightAddedBy`), ADD KEY `RateSetBy` (`RateSetBy`), ADD KEY `VHCAddedBy` (`VHCAddedBy`), ADD KEY `BelongsToWR` (`BelongsToWR`), ADD KEY `DeletedBy` (`DeletedBy`), ADD KEY `SupplierInvNo` (`SupplierInvNo`), ADD KEY `SuppDisputedBy` (`SuppDisputedBy`), ADD KEY `SuppDisputeClearedBy` (`SuppDisputeClearedBy`), ADD KEY `SuppPaidBy` (`SuppPaidBy`), ADD KEY `SuppInvCheckedBy` (`SuppInvCheckedBy`), ADD KEY `OrderConfirmedUser` (`OrderConfirmedUser`), ADD KEY `DisputeType` (`DisputeType`), ADD KEY `TicketApprovedBy` (`TicketApprovedBy`), ADD KEY `ClientDisputeClearedBy` (`ClientDisputeClearedBy`), ADD KEY `ClientDisputedBy` (`ClientDisputedBy`), ADD KEY `LeadOwnerBDM` (`LeadOwnerBDM`), ADD KEY `m_disputed` (`SuppIsDisputed`), ADD KEY `m_clientdisputed` (`ClientIsDisputed`), ADD KEY `OrigCreator` (`OrigCreator`), ADD KEY `TicketStatus` (`TicketStatus`), ADD KEY `MovementType` (`MovementType`);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a simple question, however it is hard for me since I can't see the model logic that you are trying to build.

Still, following should be the optimized version of your query, according to me:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM tblcontainergroups 
WHERE (SELECT SUM(IF(MovementType=0,1,IF(MovementType=2, -1, 0)))
    FROM tblmovements 
    WHERE GroupID=tblcontainergroups.ID AND TicketStatus=1)>0
```

Basically, you need only one sub query with conditional SUM that will sum 1s or -1s according to MovementType value, and criteria for the sub query for GroupID and TicketStatus.

Also, you need to create index for the GroupID, MovementType and TicketStatus fields (separately) in the tblmovements table.

Comment: They're all indexed already. The logic is just i'm trying to find a % of container groups that have an increase applied `LENGTH(DateOfIncreases)>4` in query 2 vs the amount of active container groups ie: query1. A container group is considered active if  there's more deliveries than removals which is the sub select part of each query :).  I avoided the  IF statement route as I assumed IF's would be more resource hungry than 2 simple sub select count.  I'll give it a try see what it behaves like.

Comment: So applied your version its not really made it much faster

Comment: Dave, I am wondering how this query will be optimized to make it faster. IS that possible to send me the data with only necessary fields that wouldn't cause a sensitive data sharing concern, so I can take a look at it in my environment?

Comment: The entire dataset of the tables in question is about 7 gb. so I think the bulk issue is that there's too much data for count() to be efficient. I could provide the database structure but there's no real way to get you a sample set of data as its that inter-related without dumping the entire table.

Comment: oh! 7 GB. Perhaps I should have asked about the data size. Now it doesn't sound so slow for millions of rows of data.

Comment: Yeah I know Im just wanting to make it go as fast as possible and I know subselects especially counts() can be quite slow typically we can speed them up by removing the subselects and going with joins etc but I can't work out a way of doing this better than I already am.